# Acer Iconia Tab A500 - Rooting & Honeycomb 3.2

Tags: rooting, 3.2-honeycomb, acer-iconia-a500

I just bought a brand new Iconia Tab A500. I just unboxed it and it shall be charging for the next 14 hours :)

While I wait for first booting it, I have a question on rooting with 3.2. The tablet comes with Honey 3.0, but I read that the 3.2 update is ready to be delivered OTA. But I absolutely want to root it!

1. Can I root the device after the OS upgrade?
2. Or should I root it first?
3. Or, does upgrade remove rooting and currently there's no [yet] rooting for HC3.2?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the 3.2 update on the A500 has not been rooted ([some discussion here](http://www.acertabletforum.com/forum/acer-iconia-tab-general-discussions/1488-updated-3-2-cannot-rooted-again.html)). There's [one XDA thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1276227) where someone has described a method of *downgrading* so you can root, but nothing that lets you root 3.2 in and of itself.

If you want to have root access then I would suggest rooting the shipped version, then manually upgrading to a [pre-rooted version](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1265847) of the latest OTA update.

Comment: Great answer. Another quick question: is it hard to brick the device if I want to try several ROMs. I mean, in the HTC devices I know that you can actually brick only when you try to flash bootloader, otherwise you'll ALWAYS have the time to flash the ROM again with another one. Does the same apply to Iconia? The last link wasn't quite assuring about safety :D

Comment: @djechelon: As long as you can get to you recovery (even stock recovery) you're okay, but I don't know if the A500 allows you to flash partitions using fastboot and the like. I've never seen anything that implies that you can, which would mean if you wrecked both your recovery and boot partitions you could be in a bad state. That's about as familiar as I am with the A500, though.