# Preparing A500 for warranty service

Tags: restore, unrooting, acer-iconia-a500, downgrade, warranty

I have a [rooted A500 with HC3.2](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/16636/acer-iconia-tab-a500-rooting-honeycomb-3-2) and I strongly believe that the [focus problem](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/20168/camera-not-focusing) is hardware. Since I'm under warranty I don't think I'll waste my time and send the tablet to repair.

Two questions:

#### How do I fully backup my device (let's say "snapshot") in order to easily restore all apps, wallpapers, settings, etc (possibly accounts too) when it returns? I can easily backup programs, but I don't know about their data. I also have a Bitcoin wallet there, so I need to back my private keys up in order to receive coins at the same address later.

#### How do I un-root and downgrade the firmware to Acer's original stock 3.0? When I updated [Recovery](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.interphaze.AcerRecoveryInstaller) I did a backup, so I believe the final step is to restore that backup.

By the way, does Acer consider rooting a warranty breach for hardware problems? I know many manufacturers don't care if you change their firmware when you send them a device with clear hardware problems, but they eventually restore everything to stock.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could have found the solution by myself. Not sure because I haven't tested it yet.

For the backup/restore: [Titanium Backup](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup) ([tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GJlsfmQJTXY))

For the downgrade/unroot thing: first I could restore Acer's original recovery via Acer recovery installer, then I could downgrade to HC3.0.1 with [this](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1276227)

<strike>I'll give it a try</strike>

## It works perfectly!!!